Is this convex or not?
Suppose I have the following function, where $p$ is a probability density and $c\in[0,1]$ is a constant:
$$
  f(p) = \mathbb{E}_{x \sim p}\left[\log\left(\frac{p(x)}{c+p(x)}\right)\right]
$$
Then is this function convex in $p$? Any help is appreciated.

What I have so far:
If we take $p_1$ and $p_2$ as densities, then for $t\in[0,1]$ by the linearity of expectation:
$$
  f(tp_1 + (1-t)p_2) = tf(p_1) + (1-t)f(p_2)
$$
But I'm not sure if we can consider disregard the $\log$ which is concave, also noting that it is negative since its argument is in $[0,1]$.

We can't apply linearity of expectation, because it's expectation with respect to different distributions. Namely, $p_1, p_2, tp_1+(1-t)p_2$ are three different distributions implicit in $$t f(p_1)+(1-t)f(p_2)=f(tp_1+(1-t)p_2).$$

I believe linearity of expectation still holds, but the expectation on the RHS will be with respect to the joint distribution

"I believe linearity of expectation still holds." Why do you believe that?

I thought the only requirement for LoE was that the densities are over the same space, not that they are the same (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Expectation_is_Linear)

Your statement references "the densities". I don't think linearity of expectation typically references densities. Can you show me an example of such?

Here's a different example to show that linearity of expectation does not hold if you change distributions. Consider the function $p\mapsto \mathbb{E}_p p$ for pdfs $p$. Let $p(x)=1$ on $(0,1)$ and $0$ elsewhere, and let $q(x)=1$ on $(1,2)$ and $0$ elsewhere. Let $r(x)=(p+q)/2$, which is $1/2$ on $(0,2)$. Then $$\mathbb{E}_pp = \int_0^1 p(x)p(x)dx=1,$$ $$\mathbb{E}_q q=\int_1^2 q(x)q(x)dx=1,$$ and $$\mathbb{E}_r r= \int_0^2 r(x)r(x)dx = \frac{1}{4}\int_0^2 dx=1/2.$$

In your the proofwiki link, in every example, all expectations are with respect to the same probability measure.

I believe that this example does not hold, since p,q are over different spaces, i.e p is over (0,1) and q over (1,2)

No. $p,q$ are both densities over $\mathbb{R}$.

Consider the continuous case on the proof wiki, the marginal densities of X,Y are not assumed to be the same

That's irrelevant. That's not what your problem is doing.

In general, an integral involves a measure and an integrand. In the continuous case of the proof wiki you linked, $X,Y$ are part of the integrand. There is only one measure, $\mathbb{P}$. All integrals are taken with respect to the same measure.
In your case, your $p_1,p_2$ are both part of the integrand and part of the measure.

Okay, I think I see what you mean now. My approach for the linearity of expectation came from Theorem 2.4.2 from here (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.11382), perhaps they are also missing this, unless I'm misunderstanding completely.

In the case of densities, linearity of expectation will hold, as long as the integrand does not also depend on the density. But it's still ultimately because of integrating against the same measure (in this case, the usual Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$). Say we have a function $f$ that does not depend on the pdf $p$. Then $$\mathbb{E}p f = \int f(x)p(x)dx.$$ so the density becomes part of the integrand, integrated against Lebesgue measure $dx$. So we have $$\mathbb{E}{tp+(1-t)q} [f] = \int f(x) [tp(x)+(1-t)q(x)]dx = t\int f(x)p(x)dx +(1-t)\int f(x)q(x)dx=\mathbb{E}_p[f]+\mathbb{E}_q[f].$$

So, with this in mind, does convexity even make sense in this context?

Yes. The question still makes sense.

We let $X:=L_1(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B},\mu)$ be the space of all (equivalence classes) of Borel-measurable functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $$\int |f(x)|d\mu(x):=\int |f(x)|dx$$ is finite, where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.  Then densities on $\mathbb{R}$ can be identified with the set $D$ of (Lebesgue almost-everywhere) non-negative members of $X$ whose integral is equal to $1$. Note that $X$ is a vector space and $D$ is a convex subset thereof. For $c\in [0,1]$, we define $U:D\to (-\infty,0]$ by $$U(p)=\mathbb{E}_{X\sim p}\log\Bigl(\frac{p(X)}{c+p(X)}\Bigr).$$  This is equal to $$\int \log\Bigl(\frac{p(x)}{c+p(x)} p(x)dx,$$ because the expectation is the integral of the integrand times the density.
We agree to the convention that the function $$\frac{p(x)}{c+p(x)}$$ is identically $1$ in the case $c=0$. The relevance of this statement is to avoid the "silly" situation in which we have some $p(x)=0$ and therefore we have $\frac{0}{0}$ as our integrand. In those cases, the distribution determined by $p$ assigns zero probability to the set where $p(x)=0$, so in any meaningful context, the value of our integrand should not matter on that set. This means that $\log\Bigl(\frac{p(x)}{0+p(x)}\Bigr)\equiv 0$, and the expectation is $0$, regardless of $p$. Therefore it is convex.
Assume $0<c$. Define $\phi:[0,\infty)\to (-\infty,0)$ by $$\phi(r)=r\log\Bigl(\frac{r}{c+r}\Bigr).$$  Note that $$\phi'(r)=\log\Bigl(\frac{r}{c+r}\Bigr)+\frac{c}{c+r}$$ and $$\phi''(r)=\frac{c}{r(c+r)}-\frac{c}{(c+r)^2}=\frac{c^2}{r(c+r)^2}>0.$$  So $\phi$ is convex on $(0,\infty)$.  By continuity, $\phi$ is convex on $[0,\infty)$.
Note that for a density function $p:\mathbb{R}\to [0,\infty)$, $$\int \phi(p(x))dx  = \int p(x)\cdot \log\Bigl(\frac{p(x)}{c+p(x)}\Bigr)dx = \int \log\Bigl(\frac{p(x)}{c+p(x)}\Bigr) p(x)dx = \mathbb{E}_{X\sim p}\Bigl(\frac{p(X)}{c+p(X)}\Bigr)=U(p).$$
Now let $p,q:\mathbb{R}\to [0,\infty)$ be measureable functions. Fix $0<t<1$. For any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, we apply the convexity of $\phi$ above to deduce that $$\phi(tp(x)+(1-t)q(x))\leqslant t\phi(p(x))+(1-t)\phi(q(x)).$$  Integrating both sides against the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ gives $$\int \phi(t p(x)+(1-t)q(x)) dx \leqslant \int t\phi(p(x))+(1-t)\phi(q(x))dx = t\int \phi(p(x))+(1-t)\phi(q(x))dx.$$  But we have already established that $$\int \phi(r(x))dx=U(r)$$ for a density $r$, so we have shown that \begin{align*} U(tp+(1-t)q) & = \int \phi(tp+(1-t)q)dx \\ & \leqslant t\int \phi(p(x))dx +(1-t)\int \phi(q(x))dx \\ &  = tU(p)+(1-t)U(q).\end{align*} So $U$ is indeed convex.
